# Where can I read the changelog for the tezos-client Docker image?

Tags: docker, tezos-client

I got notified of a new version of the Tezos client Docker images (via the shell script which accompanies it). But there's no mention of the new version number or changelog.

Where can I read the changelog of the newest version of the Tezos client Docker images?

(I have searched the Tezos Docker repository, gitlab.com/tezos/tezos and the documentation in http://tezos.gitlab.io/master/ to no avail)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like new versions, including highlight changes, are usually announced in this Tezos baking Slack channel: https://tezos-baking.slack.com/messages/CAHL22STT/convo/CB8K1F7TR-1555503213.065500/ (just apply for access if you don't have it already).

Also, releases are sometimes described further here: http://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/releases/april.html and here: https://blog.nomadic-labs.com/

Answer (score 2):

Normally, the Docker images are supposed to follow the `mainnet-staging` branch of the Tezos repository:

https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/commits/mainnet-staging

Comment: So the only way to understand what you are upgrading to is to read the full commit log? (not to mention the problem of finding out what version you are actually upgrading from)
Feeling kinda in the dark here :)